# How Should i change the value of timer in setTimeout() based on the duration of the videos in slides

Tags: javascript, video, slider, logic, slide

I implemented a slider which has 7 slides and each slides contains video in background and it slides away to 2nd slide and so on based on the `timer` value. I set the value of `timer` to the first video's duration but idk how i can update

here is the code

```js
import '../styles/index.scss'

import '@/utils/easings'
import '@/utils/polyfill'
import '@/utils/sw'

import Application from '@/classes/App'

import gsap from 'gsap'

import Draggable from 'gsap/Draggable'

window.App = new Application()

document.querySelectorAll('.header__slider').forEach((container) => {
  // Setup variables
  const items = container.querySelectorAll('.header__slide')
  const itemsMax = items.length - 1
  const thumbnail = document.querySelector('.thumbnails')

  console.log(thumbnail)

  const svgContainer = document.querySelector('.header__thumbnail__svgs')

  const svg = document.querySelector('.header__thumbnail__svg')

  const video = document.querySelector('.header__slider__slide__video')
  //   const allVideos = document.querySelectorAll('.header__slider__slide__video')

  const isPlaying = video.currentTime > 0 && !video.paused && !video.ended &&
    video.readyState > video.HAVE_CURRENT_DATA

  let index = 0
  const move = 100
  const timer = video.duration * 1000

  const duration = 1
  let autoplay
  // --------------------------------//
  //  Inital setup
  // --------------------------------//
  function svgActive (index) {
    const svgAll = svgContainer.querySelectorAll('svg')
    svgAll.forEach((svg) => {
      svg.classList.remove('active')
    })
    svgAll[index].classList.add('active')
  }

  function init () {
    // Create  Dots
    items.forEach((item, index) => {
      const number = document.createElement('button')
      number.innerHTML = index + 1

      if (index === 0) number.classList.add('active') // Set the first dot to active

      if (index === 0) svg.classList.add('active')

      // Allow clicking the dots
      number.addEventListener('click', () => {
        slideLogic(false, index)
      })

      if (thumbnail) thumbnail.appendChild(number)
    })
    // Animate the first element in
    gsap.set(items, {
      autoAlpha: 0
    })
    gsap.set(['.slider', items[index]], {
      autoAlpha: 1
    })
    gsap.from(items[index], {
      autoAlpha: 0,
      x: move
    })

    autoplay = window.setTimeout(slideLogic, timer)
  }
  // Run inital setup
  init()
  // END  Inital setup --------------//

  // --------------------------------//
  // ☝️ Touch
  // --------------------------------//
  if (window.Draggable) {
    Draggable.create(items, {
      type: 'x', // Drag only on the X axis
      zIndexBoost: false,
      onDragStart: function () {
        window.clearTimeout(autoplay) // disable autoplay
        slideLogic(this.getDirection() === 'right')
      }
    })
  }
  // END ☝️ Touch  --------------//

  // --------------------------------//
  // Set active  dot
  // --------------------------------//
  function dotActive (index) {
    const videosAll = document.querySelectorAll('.header__slider__slide__video')
    const dotsAll = thumbnail.querySelectorAll('button')
    dotsAll.forEach((dot) => {
      dot.classList.remove('active')
    })
    dotsAll[index].classList.add('active')

    if (!isPlaying) {
      videosAll[index].play()
    }
  }
  // END Set active  dot --------------//

  // --------------------------------//
  // ️ Slide animation
  // --------------------------------//
  function slideAnimation (index, moveIn, outIn) {
    // Reset the properties you are animating below
    // Ohter wise they animate from that positon (probalby not visable)
    gsap.set(items, {
      xPercent: 0,
      scale: 1
    })
    gsap.set(items[moveIn], {
      autoAlpha: 1
    })

    // The animation
    const tl = gsap.timeline({
      defaults: {
        duration
      },
      onStart: animationStart,
      onComplete: animationDone
    })
    // Move out slide
    tl.to(items[index], {
      xPercent: outIn[0]
    })
    // move in slide
    tl.from(items[moveIn], {
      xPercent: outIn[1]
    }, '<')
    // Animate text
    tl.set(items[index], {
      autoAlpha: 0
    }) // Hide moved out slide
  }

  function animationStart () {
    container.classList.add('running')
    video.load()
  }

  function animationDone () {
    autoplay = window.setTimeout(slideLogic, timer)
    container.classList.remove('running')
    gsap.set(items, {
      x: 0
    })
  }
  // END ️ Slide animation --------------//

  // --------------------------------//
  // Slider ️ logic
  // --------------------------------//
  function slideLogic (prev, customMoveIn) {
    window.clearTimeout(autoplay) // disable autoplay
    const outIn = [-move, move]
    if (prev) outIn.reverse()
    let moveIn
    // Check if moveIn is passed with the function
    if (typeof customMoveIn === 'undefined') {
      if (prev) {
        moveIn = index === 0 ? itemsMax : index - 1
      } else {
        moveIn = index === itemsMax ? 0 : index + 1
      }
    } else {
      moveIn = customMoveIn
    }
    if (thumbnail) dotActive(moveIn) // Set active dot
    if (thumbnail) svgActive(moveIn) // Set active svg
    slideAnimation(index, moveIn, outIn) // Animation function
    // Changing the next index
    if (typeof customMoveIn === 'undefined') {
      if (prev) {
        index === 0 ? (index = itemsMax) : index--
      } else {
        index === itemsMax ? (index = 0) : index++
      }
    } else {
      index === itemsMax ? (index = 0) : (index = customMoveIn++)
    }
  }
})
```

`autoplay` is making the slides to slide automatically which contains `timer` value that i want to update

here is raw codepen link
https://codepen.io/raj-shukla/pen/rNKjKzN?editors=0010

Comment: if i get it right i think you can check if timer = videolength at slider change function and if it not equal make it equal :v

Comment: It looks like the same video is being used by slide containers - did you mean `container` instead of `document` in `document.querySelector(".slide__figure__video")`? You also need to wait until a ['loadedmetadata' event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/loadedmetadata_event) has fired on a video before accessing its duration.

Comment: @traktor yeah it is using the same first video's duration for each of them which i not want i want the timer value to be updated on each slide but idk how i can query it in setTimeout() if there is any option i can able to build the logic after then, can you check the codepen

Comment: There are issues before looking at `setTimeout`, e.g. `isPlaying` should be a function, not a constant (set to `false` during initiation),  the value of `const timer = video.duration * 1000` is `NaN` because it's being read too early,  and  an `ended` event is fired on video elements when they finish playing, making the use of `setTimeout` a little oversimplified. Please consider presenting a *cut down* version of the timing problem (the "slide show" can be mocked with console logs) as a [code snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/5217142)  in the question.